# Pass the data the user enters into our URL, receive the XML

Tags: iphone

'pass the data the user enters into our URL, receive the XML ' How this can be implement

Answer (score 0):

See [UsingNSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).